# How to make the header with the logo on the left and the navigation on the right?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, header, media-queries

I'd want to make the header to my web page where the logo would be on the left hand side and the horizontal navigation bar on the right hand side.

The problem is that whenever I shrink the browser window the navigation bar goes below the border of the header container, thus violating the page's structure.

Like this: 
[image]

Are there any solutions? I can only think of making the parent container Header accommodate its height to the child containers, but I don't know how to implement that. Or should I use the media queries somehow?

I wrote the following code.

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: url('img/background.gif');
}
#logo {
  float: left;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what effect you want to have. If you shrink and the nav bar doesn't go to new line, it will just overlay the header, which is not good. how exactly do you want this to be handled when the window is shrunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the flex model or min-height + overflow to deal with floatting elements. You can also use both together, float properties will be overidden by flex where supported. ,

```css
header {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: url('img/background.gif');
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden; /* for float if flex not supported */
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  /* to deal with flex */
  flex-shrink:0;
  margin:auto;/* or 0 or auto auto auto 0 or ... */
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/140x45&text=logo.png">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having your li display "inline-block"? I think you'd have to take the block setting off "li a".
Then you may have to give a set width to the ul itself so that it does shrink with the page or use media queries.
I hope this helps :)